# MPAndroid bar chat is showing zero values in middle if all the values are zeros

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

Im using MPAndroidChart for bar chart with some values.. If I get all the values are zero then its like below. Please anybody help how to show zero in bottom or hide if graph if all the values are zero

```
implementation 'com.github.Philjay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

private fun drawWeightBarChart(weightData: ArrayList<BarEntry>?) {
    // barChart = findViewById<View>(R.id.barChart) as BarChart
    val barDataSet = BarDataSet(weightData, "")
    //barDataSet.barBorderWidth = 0.9f
    //barDataSet.valueFormatter = MyValueFormatter()
    barDataSet.setColors(Color.parseColor("#20D2FF"))
    val barData = BarData(barDataSet)

    barData.setValueFormatter(MyValueFormatter())

    val xAxis: XAxis = weight_chart.getXAxis()
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

    val yAxisRight: YAxis = weight_chart.getAxisRight()
    val yAxisLeft: YAxis = weight_chart.getAxisLeft()

    yAxisRight.isEnabled = false
    yAxisLeft.isEnabled = false

    //yAxisLeft.setAxisMaxValue(20f);

    weight_chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    val leg: Legend = weight_chart.getLegend()
    leg.isEnabled = false

    weight_chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    weight_chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    weight_chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    val months =
        arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
    val formatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(months)
    xAxis.granularity = 1f
    xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
    weight_chart.setData(barData)
    weight_chart.setFitBars(true)
    weight_chart.animateXY(500, 500)
    weight_chart.invalidate()

}
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue, even reverted to older version 3.0.3. Replaced new ValueFormatter with IAxisValueFormatter with same result

Comment: @RahulKahale Did u solve this issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64620752/1029110 chartView.groupBars was problematic in my case. The answer below this link says total to zero, my case its working when totals to 1. `// (0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"` line present in sample code

Answer (score 2):

You should set the minimum value of your axis to 0 using setAxisMinValue, like this:

```
weight_chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(0);
weight_chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(0);
```

Kotlin:

```
weight_chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = (0F)
weight_chart.axisRight.axisMinimum = (0F)
```